# R: Count percentage of "yes" in a column by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to count the percentage of the response "yes" in a column that contains "yes" and "no".

| Student | Response |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | yes |
| S2 | yes |
| S1 | no |
| S5 | yes |
| S5 | yes |
| S7 | no |
| S8 | no |

This is what I would like to get

| Student | Response | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | yes | 50% |
| S2 | yes | 100% |
| S1 | no | 50% |
| S5 | yes | 100% |
| S5 | yes | 100% |
| S7 | no | 0% |
| S8 | no | 0% |

This is what I have been working but I don't understand what's not working. Thanks!

```
df %>%
group_by(Student)%>%
summarize(sum_total = n(Response)%>%
filter(Response== "yes") %>%
summarize(sum_yes = n(Response))%>%
mutate(yes_percentage = scales::label_percent()(sum_yes/sum_total))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the base function `ave`

```
dat$percentage <- scales::label_percent()(ave( dat$Response=="yes", dat$Student, FUN=mean))

dat
  Student Response percentage
1      S1      yes        50%
2      S2      yes       100%
3      S1       no        50%
4      S5      yes       100%
5      S5      yes       100%
6      S7       no         0%
7      S8       no         0%
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple `group_by` and `mutate` will do the job.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = label_percent()(sum(Response == "yes")/n()))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   Student [5]
  Student Response Percent
  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  
1 S1      yes      50%    
2 S2      yes      100%   
3 S1      no       50%    
4 S5      yes      100%   
5 S5      yes      100%   
6 S7      no       0%     
7 S8      no       0%
```